# Difference in connecting mysql functions?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell the difference between the php functions `mysql_connect()`,`mysql_pconnect()` and `mysqli_connect()`? So that it will be a reference for all with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `connect()` and `pconnect()`, it is simply like a shop when you entering a shop you will open the door and take your item, come out and close the door. That is called `connect()` in mysql. The connection to the mysql database will be automatically closed when the script terminates. 
When the door of the shop is already opened and never closed it is called `pconnect()`, open a connection with `mysql_pconnect()`, the connection will not be closed and will "persist" for future use.

Read more: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_mysql_connect_and_mysql_pconnect_in_PHP#ixzz1xZfVfXzv

difference from mysqli and mysql:

There are different opinions on which connector/extension is faster. Here is a simple guideline that you should follow:

If the MySQL database you are connecting to is <= 4.1.3, then use mysql_connect.
If the MySQL database you are connecting to is > 4.1.3, then use mysqli_connect.

Though you can use mysql_connect with newer versions there are certain functions you cannot access.

Answer (score 1):

Differences are explained in detail here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP checks if there's already an identical persistent connection (that remained open from earlier) - and if it exists, it uses it. If it does not exist, it creates the link. An 'identical' connection is a connection that was opened to the same host, with the same username and the same password (where applicable).

Check these links --
[Link 1](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)
[Link 2](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

mysqli is a extension of php. I will not recommend to use it because there are rumors around that will be obsolete in future versions of php.